# Insert .SVG into specific coordinates on an .SVG object

Tags: css, html, svg

I have a website which have an SVG object, I would like to be able to insert a dynamic SVG object into the parent SVG object on a specific location (The dynamic SVG always have a fixed size).

This is my SVG code:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 355 355" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYmax" class="hero_figure">
  <g id="hero_create" class="hero_create">
    <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" x="213" y="103" width="140" height="20" transform="rotate(20 283,113.00000000000003) " rx="10" class="hero_right_arm" id="hero_right_arm" />
    <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" x="-2" y="103" width="140" height="20" transform="rotate(-20 67.99999999999997,112.99999999999999) " rx="10" class="hero_left_arm" id="hero_left_arm" />
    <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x="138" y="78" width="75" height="120" rx="10" class="hero_body" id="hero_body" />
    <ellipse fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" cx="175.5" cy="38" rx="41" ry="35.5" class="hero_head" id="hero_head" />
    <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x="110.5" y="198" width="20" height="150" transform="rotate(20 120.50000000000009,273) " rx="10" class="hero_left_leg" id="hero_left_leg" />
    <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x="221" y="198" width="20" height="150" rx="10" transform="rotate(-20 231.0000000000001,273) " class="hero_right_leg" id="hero_right_leg" />
  </g>
  <g id="hero_item_slot" class="hero_item_slot">
    <rect opacity="0.5" height="75" width="75" y="94.5" x="275" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" class="hero_right_arm_item_slot" id="hero_right_arm_item_slot" />
    <rect opacity="0.5" height="75" width="75" y="94.5" x="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" class="hero_left_arm_item_slot" id="hero_left_arm_item_slot" />
    <rect opacity="0.5" height="75" width="75" y="-0.5" x="137.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" class="hero_head_item_slot" id="hero_head_item_slot" />
    <rect opacity="0.5" height="75" width="75" y="100" x="138" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" class="hero_body_item_slot" id="hero_body_item_slot" />
    <rect opacity="0.5" height="75" width="75" y="269.5" x="215" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" class="hero_right_leg_item_slot" id="hero_right_leg_item_slot" />
    <rect opacity="0.5" height="75" width="75" y="269.5" x="60" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" class="hero_left_leg_item_slot" id="hero_left_leg_item_slot" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

What I am trying to do is insert an object into each of the rectangles in hero_item_slot where the item will always have a fixed size of 74x74.

So for example insert a SVG into hero_right_leg_item_slot with the size of 74x74.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: getElementById("hero_item_slot").appendChild(yourDynamicSVGObject)

Comment: @RobertLongson, I am not sure how to exactly use that to insert in a specific location.

Comment: insertBefore will do that if you provide one of your rect elements as the second argument.

Comment: @RobertLongson, It did not work for me. I made an SVG called "test" and tried to add it like this $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hero_right_arm_item_slot").html($("#test"));
}); 
It got added in the source code, but i was not able to see the svg file. I also tried to only add the g element, but that did not work too.

Comment: Okay, so i found out how to add in svg objects with @RobertLongson method, but the problem is that they are just added in, they are not in the right position. I wanted the SVG I include to be inside the hero_right_arm_item_slot but instead it is just where the imported SVG coordinates tells it to be.

How can I do so it is inside the hero_right_arm_item_slot, so it makes it's own coordinate system inside that rectangle

Comment: So i found the solution :) 
Thanks a lot @RobertLongson for the help, i just had to use a transform="translate(x,y)" to position it the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up fixing it after help from @RobertLongson.

index.php:

```
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(1, 95.5)" class="hero_left_arm_item" id="hero_left_arm_item">

                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(138.5, 0.5)" class="hero_head_item" id="hero_head_item">

                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(139, 101)" class="hero_body_item" id="hero_body_item">

                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(216, 270.5)" class="hero_right_leg_item" id="hero_right_leg_item">

                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(61, 270.5)" class="hero_left_leg_item" id="hero_left_leg_item">

                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
```

In the last one is where I insert the data. 
I use the `Transform="translate(X,Y)` to set the position of the original box. 
Then to insert an object i just use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hero_right_arm_item").html($("#test"));
    $("#hero_left_arm_item").html($("#test"));
    $("#hero_head_item").html($("#test"));
    $("#hero_body_item").html($("#test"));
    $("#hero_right_leg_item").html($("#test"));
    $("#hero_left_leg_item").html($("#test"));
});
```

The svg i use looks like this:

```
    <svg id="test" width="75" height="75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
        <g>
            <rect fill="#ff007f" id="canvas_background" height="75" width="75" y="-1" x="-1"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect id="svg_1" height="28" width="41" y="29.5" x="17.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#A4FFFF"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I do not need to remove the SVG tags, as I am able to insert an SVG directly inside an SVG.

Hope this can help somebody, and thanks to @RobertLongson for helping with the JS and Method-Draw for making the tool i drawed the SVG files in.